# Как определить, целое число или нет?

Tags: php, функции

Какая функцию, которая определяет, является число целым или нет? Мне это нужно для того, чтобы если число целое, оставить его без изменений, если нет - извлечь из него целое число и прибавить единицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is_int()
```

Answer (score 2):

"чтобы если число целое, оставить его без изменений, если нет - извлечь из него целое число и прибавить единицу" - т.е. округлить в большую сторону? Функция ceil().